# Leer array desde un archivo en PHP con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo un array guardado en un archivo dentro de una carpeta que he creado en App llamada Arrays. Es el siguiente:

```
$contentTypeArray=array(
    1  => 'TEXTO',
    2 => 'PDF',
    3 => 'PPT',
    4 => 'AUDIO',
    5 => 'VIDEO',
    6 => 'HTML',
    );
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder a dicho array? Sé utilizar Colecciones pero tampoco sé como acceder al documento.

Comment: Lo has guardado en un archivo así como lo has mostrado? Por qué no lo metes como json_encode aunque sea? De como acceder no tengo ni idea :S

Comment: Una alternativa sería meterlo en formato JSON. Lo que no sé es como acceder

Comment: La cosa es evitar guardarlo en una base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema tiene mas de 2 soluciones posibles.
1 crear un fichero donde pones el arreglo, nombrarlo como un archivo de php por ejemplo arreglo.php, posicionarlo en algún directorio de tu proyecto e incluirlo donde lo vayas a usar con una instrucción include_once 'camino_al_archivo'

La 2da opción es guardar los datos del arreglo como un json en un archivo y posteriormente leer el archivo, y decodificar el json.

En la primera opción tu archivo del arreglo quedaria como:

```
<?php
$contentTypeArray=array(
1  => 'TEXTO',
2 => 'PDF',
3 => 'PPT',
4 => 'AUDIO',
5 => 'VIDEO',
6 => 'HTML',
);
```

Y en donde quieras usarlo solo debes poner al comienzo del archivo

```
 include_once 'ruta_al_fichero.php';
```

y lo puedes usar como si lo hubieras declarado en este mismo fichero, con el mismo nombre de variable

La segunda opción tendrias que salvar tu arreglo como un json

```
$fichero = fopen("ruta_donde_voy_a_guardar_el_archivo","w+");
$fichero->write($fichero, json_encode($mi_arreglo));
fclose($fichero);
```

Ahora si quieres leerlo tendrias que cargarlo desde la ruta donde lo almacenastes

```
$ruta = "ruta_donde_guardastes_el_archivo";
$fichero = fopen($ruta,"r");
$contenido = fread($fichero,filesize($ruta));
//Ya en mi_arreglo tienes el arreglo original
$mi_arreglo = json_decode($contenido);
```

Comment: Recuerda que la ruta del archivo es relativa al fichero donde quieres usar el arreglo. Por si guardas el json en otro directorio. Te recomiendo obtener el path de tu proyecto y apartir de ahí armar tu ruta.